# Custom validate attribute on query parameter web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, custom-attributes, validationattribute

I have the following controller which takes guids in string format as query parameters.

I wanted to verify they were a valid guid before executing the method but I'm not sure how to fire my custom ValidationAttribute:

controller.cs

```
public async Task<Profile> GetProfile([ValidGuid] string id)
{
    ...
}
```

ValidGuidAttribute.cs

```
internal class ValidGuidAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid.Parse(value.ToString());
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidIdException($"{value.ToString()} is an invalid id");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help pointing out how to fire my `IsValid` method would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a route constraint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints

```
[Route("getprofile/{id:guid}")]
public async Task<Profile> GetProfile(string id)
{
    ...
}
```